# Pasar un objeto de un activity a otro

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

tengo unas dudas respecto a como pasar objetos entre activitys. Estoy trabajando en una lista de la compra en la que tengo dos activitys, la principal que muestra la lista de productos con unos datos y un botón "Añadir" que me lleva a la otra Activity donde o bien puedo modificar los datos de un producto o bien crear uno nuevo. En esta segunda Activity tengo dos botones, uno para actualizar los datos del producto o bien añadirlo a la lista y el otro para eliminar el producto de esa lista. Llevo un tiempo mirando y dándole vueltas al asunto y no se como pasar un objeto de tipo "Producto" a la ListView del primer Activity creándolo con el botón del segundo Activity. Intento hacerlo mediante intents, `putExtra()` y que el dato lo reciba en el método `onResume()` del primer Activity ya que he pensado que es el método donde tendría que hacerse eso al pasar del segundo Activity al primero. Adjunto código para mostrar lo que tengo hecho a ver que estoy haciendo mal o que es lo que no entiendo.

Activity Main

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
        ListView listaProductos;
        List<Producto> productosList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            Button botonAñadir = findViewById(R.id.botonAñadir);
            botonAñadir.setOnClickListener(this);
    
            //Creación del objeto de la base de datos y creación de la variable para hacer referencia a la base de datos y trabajar sobre ella
            SQLiteOpenHelper productosdbh = new SQLiteOpenHelper(this, "DBProductos", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = productosdbh.getWritableDatabase();
    
            //Añadimos a la lista de productos y a la base de datos unos productos por defecto para que los cargue al iniciar la App
            listaProductos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProductos);
            productosList.add(new Producto("Palomitas", "Pelofritas", "", "0,50", "100g", "1"));
            productosList.add(new Producto("Panceta", "Hacendado", "", "2,60", "350g", "1"));
            productosList.add(new Producto("Croissants", "Hacendado", "", "0,90", "250g", "1"));
            productosList.add(new Producto("Coca Cola", "Hacendado", "", "0,30", "300g", "5"));
    
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Productos (nombre,marca,precio,peso,cantidad) VALUES ('Palomitas','Pelofritas',0.50,100,1) ");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Productos (nombre,marca,precio,peso,cantidad) VALUES ('Pacenta','Hacendado',2.60,350,1) ");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Productos (nombre,marca,precio,peso,cantidad) VALUES ('Croissants','Hacendado',0.90,250,1) ");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Productos (nombre,marca,precio,peso,cantidad) VALUES ('Coca cola','Hacendado',0.30,300,5) ");
    
            //Creamos y linkeamos un adaptador personalizado a nuestra view
            AdaptadorProductos adProductos = new AdaptadorProductos(
                    this,
                    R.layout.producto_item,
                    productosList
            );
    
            listaProductos.setAdapter(adProductos);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Producto productoRecibido = (Producto) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("producto");
            productosList.add(productoRecibido);
        }
    
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetallesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Activity Secundaria

```
    public class DetallesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
        Producto producto = null;
        String nombre,marca,precio,peso,cantidad;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalles);
            Button botonGuardar = findViewById(R.id.botonGuardar);
            botonGuardar.setOnClickListener(this);
            Button botonEliminar = findViewById(R.id.botonEliminar);
            botonEliminar.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    
            if(view.getId() == R.id.botonGuardar){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                EditText nombreProducto = findViewById(R.id.nombre);
                nombre = nombreProducto.getText().toString();
                EditText marcaProducto = findViewById(R.id.marca);
                marca = marcaProducto.getText().toString();
                EditText precioProducto = findViewById(R.id.precio);
                precio = nombreProducto.getText().toString();
                EditText pesoProducto = findViewById(R.id.peso);
                peso = pesoProducto.getText().toString();
                EditText cantidadProducto = findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
                cantidad = cantidadProducto.getText().toString();
                producto = new Producto(nombre,marca,"",precio,peso,cantidad);
                intent.putExtra("producto",producto);
                startActivity(intent);
    
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.botonEliminar){
    
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para obtener datos de otra actividad debes iniciarla con **startActivityForResult** y los datos los obtienes no en el *OnResume*, sino en *onActivityResult*. Si cuando vayas a iniciar esa actividad deseas pasarle datos, utilizas el método *putExtra* del intent de la actividad que vas a iniciar. Si lo que deseas es pasar un objeto completo, debes implementar la interfaz *Parcelable*.

Comment: Cuando puedas [lee esto](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide?hl=es-419). Android ha desarrollado una serie de componentes que facilitan bastante tareas como estas: Componentes de Arquitectura, Componentes de Navegación, Data BInding... Hay una curva de aprendizaje al principio, pero cuando trabajas con esas herramientas vas sobre ruedas. No es sólo facilidad en el código, sino también optimización. Por ejemplo los Componentes de arquitectura permiten manejar mejor el ciclo de vida de la App, adaptarla a futuras evoluciones con menor esfuerzo, etc.

Comment: Otra gran ventaja es el uso de Room como base de datos, la cual está también incorporada de forma nativa a todas las herramientas antes descritas. De hecho, hoy día ya se habla en Android de aplicaciones con una sola Activity y todo lo demás se conecta a través de fragmentos, pudiendo pasar datos de una parte a otra con una facilidad pasmosa (gracias a los [Componentes de Navegación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate) y a [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)). Hace poco empecé a migrar mi App a ese modelo y es impresionante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo que tratas de enviar el objeto mediante un `Intent`:

```
 producto = new Producto(nombre,marca,"",precio,peso,cantidad);
 intent.putExtra("producto",producto);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Para enviarlo, implementa en tu objeto `Producto` la clase `Serializable` o Parcelable:

```
public class Producto implements Serializable {
```

Lo recibirías dentro de `onCreate()` de la `Activity` destino de esta forma:

```
 Producto productoRecibido = (Producto) getIntent().getSerializable("producto");
```

---

Lo que necesitas es **Recuperar valores de una Activity**.

para realizar esto, primeramente agrega la dependencia en tu archivo `build.grade`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    //*OnActivityResult
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.3.1'
}
```

Crea una variable de tipo ActivityResultLauncher:

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // Recibe objeto
                        ...
                        ...
                        ...
                    }else{
                        //No recibe información.
                        
                    }
                }
            });
```

Ahora para abrir la Activity desde la cual recibirías el objeto lo realizas de esta forma:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        mStartForResult.launch(intent);
```

Al cerrar la Activity desde la cual enviarías el objeto, puedes sobre escrbir el método onBackPressed() y ahí definir el objeto que retornarías:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("producto",producto);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

de esta forma en la Activity inicial recibirías el objeto.

Revisa este ejemplo completo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-OnActivityResult

Comment: El tema es que necesito enviar un objeto cada vez que pase del activity secundario al primario, ya que quiero añadir el objeto a un arraylist y que me aparezca en un ListView, entonces si lo hago así en onCreate ¿no me va a funcionar no?

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es *traer* un objeto al activity principal, necesitas usar [`startActivityForResult()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: ok @Flaxx veo que necesitas pero desde el activity secundario al primario. Editaré mi respuesta

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys si en efecto necesito que desde un segundo Activity se añadan elementos a una ListView de el activityMain